# How to get LinearLayout's X and Y coordinates?

Tags: java, android

Say I have created a linearlayout ( linLayBtn ) and added it to an already existing in the xml linearlayout ( linLayRow )...

```
linLayRow.addView(linLayBtn, linLayBtnPar);
```

And now I need to know the X and Y coordinates of the linLayBtn layout that I just added.

How would you do that?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would want it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x=linLayBtn.getLeft();
y=linLayBtn.getTop();
```

Comment: value is relative to the parent of this linLayBtn layout.

Comment: ouch, need relative to the screen.

Comment: find the left of the parent layout and adding it to the left of this layout, you will get x relative to the screen

Answer (score 1):

```
x = linLayBtn.getX();
y = linLayBtn.getY();
```

Just remember that calling this in the constructor gives back 0 because views have to be measured and laid out first.

Answer (score 0):

currentsdk < sdk 11

```
getLeft(), getTop()
```

currentsdk >= sdk 11

```
getX(), getY()
```